# How to Facebook login with associated user record in our system

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter

We have our own registration and login system.

Many of our users are users of facebook and often forget login details to our site so it would be good if they could login to our site using their FB account.

What would be the simplest way to associate their FB account with their user record in our system.

I guess there is no way to avoid a double login for the first time? i.e. login to facebook, then login to our system so they are paired so to speak. We store their facebook id in their user record and future visits would only require a FB login.

Any opinions or suggestions very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

There could be various solutions suggested for the scenario mentioned, few could be as follows:

1. I hope you currently have an Email field in your database, just add another field to store FB id.
2. Provide an interface in your application, where logged-in users can associate their facebook account with their account in your application.

For not logged-in users, you can fetch email address from FB, and do a quick look-up if the email already exists in your system, and if it exists you can update the FB id field in the DB.

If its the other way, email doesn't exists, you can add a new account into your user table.

Comment: This is basically what my website uses. It went wrong for a few users using FB proxy email addresses which is annoying, so providing a 'merge accounts' thing for users is handy as long as they understand and can easily be prompted.

Comment: So perhaps try to lookup email first if no match then they need to login to their account (with us) to associate but only once. The best we can do I think?

Answer (score 0):

i think OAuth Library from Philsturgeon's can help you to solve your problem check this library

[OAuth](https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-oauth2)

also check documentation of this here

[Oauth Doc at Spark](http://getsparks.org/packages/oauth2/versions/HEAD/show)